# power method and inverse iteration

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

True or False and please justify this answer. 
when the power method is applied to find the largest eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector of a matrix, the vectors are normalized at each step in order to increase the rate of convergence of the method.

Comment: What is your opinion on this ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange ! As Jose pointed out, you should improve this question. As it is posted now, it is likely to be closed or even deleted. For a start, describe the power method more precise.